# jquery loading localhost, encoding?

Tags: jquery, xampp, localhost

i want to develop my project on localhost, but jquery not
loading properly ... On production server,- no problems.

I use XAMPP on Windows 10, Netbeans.
I think some problem with encoding settings ???

Any idea ?[image]

Comment: No... its the same code as online version. Thats not the problem ;-)

Comment: Already checked ... Its no a new project. Only problem on localhost.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Yes, it may be so. But in that case your answer should work.

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to figure out with @JulianFuerderer why it's not.

Comment: Your screen-shot shows Chrome's *Application* tab. Are you talking about a web application that's meant to work off-line?

Answer (score 0):

May the version you've localy is corrupted, try to load it from the cdnjs like :

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes, already tried that. But then next loading js file gets same problem (owlCarousel)

Comment: Not sure what you mean, could you please clarify more?